# Why is Response.getEntity() null?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, resources, jax-rs

Env(Jboss AS 7 , Wildfly 8 )

previously i was able to dive into a project using jax-rs. where a jax-rs resource had the task to gateway another jax-rs resource.
while implementing, i found Response.newFrom() and it sounded great for that kind of task the gateway component had.
Also the java doc states that it could be used for that kind of use case 
"Note that if the entity is backed by an un-consumed input stream, the reference to the stream is copied."

But actually the first test went red. So digging a bit deeper, i found the following implementation

```
public static ResponseBuilder fromResponse(Response response) {
    ResponseBuilder b = status(response.getStatus());
    if (response.hasEntity()) {
        b.entity(response.getEntity());
    }
    for (String headerName : response.getHeaders().keySet()) {
        List<Object> headerValues = response.getHeaders().get(headerName);
        for (Object headerValue : headerValues) {
            b.header(headerName, headerValue);
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

And `getEntity()` returns Null !!

for everyone that has the same problem, i ended up doing this ..

```
    private <R> Response asNewResponse(Response response, GenericType<EntityType> sourceType, Function<EntityType, R> transformer ) {
    boolean backed = response.bufferEntity();
    if (backed) {
        if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            Addresses entity = response.readEntity(sourceType);
            return Response.status(response.getStatus()).entity(transformer.apply(entity)).build();
        } else
            return Response.status(response.getStatus()).entity(response.readEntity(new GenericType<String>() {
            })).build();
    } else {
        if (response.getEntity() instanceof EntityType) {
            return Response.status(response.getStatus()).entity(transformer.apply((EntityType)response.getEntity())).build();
        }
        return Response.status(response.getStatus()).entity(response.getEntity()).build();
    }
}
```

im not that happy about completely reading the stream, so if anybody knows why getEntity() returns null... feel free

Comment: the part ```b.entity(response.getEntity())``` should take care of  the response stream copying.

Comment: damn youre right , the javadoc of the getter says that it should return an unconsumed input stream if there is any, but the wildfly 8.1.0.Final returns null ..

Comment: even a jboss as 7 returns null ...when calling the `getEntity()` @maress